# Como paralelizar (OpenMP) uma chamada de método?

Tags: c, openmp

Então, estou desenvolvendo um trabalho para realizar a comparação de uma execução sequencial e paralela de um método de Pattern Matching. O meu input é um .txt de dezenas de linhas, que eu percorro e armazeno dentro de um buffer:

```
...
fread(buffer, sizeof(char), numero_bytes, aux);
```

Feito isso, eu executo uma vez sequencialmente:

```
       /* quebro a string em varias linhas*/
      char * string_sequencial = strtok(strdup(buffer), str);

      /*Enquanto existir linhas a serem verificadas: */
      while(string_sequencial != NULL) {

        if(match(padrao, string_sequencial)) // Método Pattern Matching
            {
              cont_padroes_sequencial++;
            }

        /*vai para a proxima linha*/
        string_sequencial  = strtok(NULL, str); 

        /*Conta o numero de linhas para o for da execução paralela*/
        n_linha++;           
      }
```

Até aqui tudo bem, o meu problema é que, quando eu utilizo mais de uma thread em:

```
omp_set_num_threads(1);
```

A execução termina.

A minha ideia era fazer igual a execução sequencial. Para cada linha, seria alocada uma thread para realizar a verificação, mas imagino que não funcione simplesmente assim.

O trecho da paralelização:

```
  char * string_paralelo = strtok(strdup(buffer), str);
  // <<< 

  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    omp_set_num_threads(1);
    #pragma omp for
    for(int i = 0; i < n_linha; i++)
        {
         if(match(padrao, string_paralelo))
            {
              cont_padroes_paralelo++;
            }
          string_paralelo  = strtok(NULL, str);
        }
  }
```

**Minha duvida:** Preciso declarar de alguma forma diferente?  Está faltando alguma coisa? Se alguém puder me dar uma luz, ficaria muito grato!

Ainda, se alguém souber: por que com uma unica thread funciona? Imagino que não é executado sequencialmente, mesmo com uma unica thread, pois o tempo de execução é menor do que a da sequencial..

Answer (score 1):

Para quem estiver interessado ou se algum dia alguém tiver a mesma duvida, eu consegui resolver o meu problema.

O problema era que, do jeito que eu estava fazendo, eu não mantinha nenhum "índice" apontado para as strings que eu gostaria de paralelizar. E por isso (acho eu) que o meu programa "crashava", pois as threads não tinha noção da ordem que era para ser executado. Então, eu resolvi criar um array para serializar as strings.

```
while(string_sequencial != NULL) {

        transforma_linha(string_sequencial); /*LETRAS MINUSCULAS*/

          // Array adicionado:
```

> ```
>         array[i] = string_sequencial;
>         i++;
> ```

```
        if(match(padrao, string_sequencial))  /* CONTABILIZA PADRÃO*/
            {
              //printf("%s \n", string_sequencial);
              cont_padroes_sequencial++;
            }

        string_sequencial  = strtok(NULL, str);  /*ITERA PARA PROXIMA LINHA*/
        n_linha++;                               /*CONTA QUANTIDADE DE LINHAS*/
      }
```

E, para a paralelização, adicionei o parametro "reduction", que, pelo o que eu entendi, evita que as threads sobrescrevam os valores uma das outras.

```
#pragma omp parallel
  {
    #pragma omp for reduction(+:cont_padroes_paralelo) // Inclusão do REDUCTION
    for(int i = 0; i < n_linha; i++)
        {
         if(match(padrao, array[i]))  // SE ACHOU UM PADRÃO, CONTABILIZA.
            {
              cont_padroes_paralelo++;
            }
        }
  }
```

Comment: a cláusula `reduction` faz uma _redução_, isto é, combina os valores de `cont_padroes_paralelo` obtidos por todas as threads através do tipo de redução especificado, nesse caso o `+`: soma todos os valores